# Posting data at clients side localhost from server

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I would like to **POST** some *JSON* data at clients side **localhost** from my Web *Application*.

I tried using **localhost** but this refers to the *Server Side - **Localhost***. I also tried to use **Javascript** instead of **PHP** but this didn't work as well.

The goal I am trying to achieve is to be able to send some data to the clients **localhost** where an other desktop application will be listening to a specific port and then do some work *(like printing a label)* with the given data.

Code I tried:

(I am using XAMPP as a **localhost** test server)

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'localhost',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: 'json',
  success: function(json) { ... },
  error: function(error) { ... }
});
```

Comment: where is the code you have tried ?

Comment: please put your code here..

Comment: I added a snippet of the code I have tried

Comment: You might need a port after localhost depending on where your server is running?

Comment: @DaraJava The problem is that code is running on the server side so *localhost* does not refer to the client side (port isn't the issue). For example, localhost goes to https://www.example.com/index.php instead of localhost/index.php

Comment: Can you access localhost from your browser?

Comment: @DaraJava yes I can. But the server cannot see the client side localhost. My problem is that I cannot post to the client side localhost.

Comment: what is the path of your localhost... maybe you did not mention it

Comment: @MasihAnsari What do you mean path. It is a website that is trying to POST to the client side **localhost** (not its own server)

Comment: imagine some strange website posts data to your pc via browser ! how the hack should that even work out ? and what is your intention behind this somewhat weird idea ?

Comment: You could generate a file with an extension that you have linked to that specific desktop program, so it automatically opens the file with it.

Comment: @sintakonte as I said in my question I would like to print some labels (imagine a printer for barcodes) whenever the user clicks print on a product.

Answer (score 0):

are you referring to a server and client within a local private network? If so, you can just specify the IP address and port of the client when sending the post request.

Ex:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: '192.168.xxx.xxx:8080',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: 'json',
  success: function(json) { ... },
  error: function(error) { ... }
});
```